# Pull data From an Object based on shortcode (path) parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, object

I working on custom function for `Wordpress`.

I have big object:

```
{
  "name": "Jon",
  "personal_information": {
            "Age": "18",
            "School": 'School_name',
            },
  "rewards": {
        "soccer": {
              "display": 'Hello soccer',
              "rate": 5,
              "type": 'soccer',
              },
          }
  }
```

User can get this information via shortcode:

```
[info name] // Will display "Jon"

[info rewards soccer display] // Will display "Hello soccer"
```

So shortcode is an actually array:

```
info = Array ()
     [0] -> rewards
     [1] -> soccer
     [2] -> display
```

And to get data from object I'm doing:

```
echo $object -> $info[0]->$info[1]->$info[2];
```

Is it any way to do same through the loop?

So I'll not have something like `$info[0]->$info[1]->$info[2];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `while` loop as:

```
$info = json_decode('{"name": "Jon","personal_information": {"Age": "18","School": "School_name"},"rewards": {"soccer": {"display": "Hello soccer","rate": 5,"type": "soccer"}}}');

 $arr = explode(" ", "info rewards soccer display");
 array_shift($arr); // remove the name of the object - info
 $res = $info;
 while (count($arr)) {
     $key = array_shift($arr);
     $res = $res->$key;
 }
 echo $res; // prints Hello soccer
```